# How to get the value after updating the table using triggers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the value after updating the table using triggers in sql

Comment: Can you please be more specific please, can you add details about your sql statement and desired values ?

Comment: After updting the table i want to get that updated value..simple

Comment: Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - you need to tell us which **concrete** RDBMS you're using - is it `mysql`? `postgresql` ? `sql-server` ? `oracle` ? Something else entirely?? Please add a relevant tag...

Comment: Sql Server bro........

Answer (score 1):

Having a scenario like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT, txt VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #tmp ( id, txt )
VALUES  ( 1, 'abc')
```

You can return the values using OUTPUT (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) during an UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE #tmp SET
    txt = 'xyz'
OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.txt
```

You can return any column from your table - INSERTED will contain new data while DELETED will contain previous data.

Answer (score 0):

In the Update SQL it self you can use [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

In the triggers on MS SQL servers there are to temp tabels called INSERED and DELETED see her for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Hope it helps.